# translateM makes object disappear from view port

Tags: android, matrix, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have started to learn OpenGL ES 2.0. I currently am trying to make an object dynamic by using the translateM method on it on the onDrawFrame() method. Unfortunately, when I do this, the object appears briefly and then disappears. I'm not sure what is going on. If I put the same code for translating it in onSurfaceChanged(), it works. Here is my code(without the x integer that should move it on the x-axis, so I know it wouldn't move. But even removing the dynamic int has it disappearing):

```
  package com.background.gl.glcirclebackgroundanimation;

import static android.opengl.GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glClear;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glClearColor;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glViewport;
import static android.opengl.Matrix.multiplyMM;
import static android.opengl.Matrix.setIdentityM;
import static android.opengl.Matrix.translateM;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;

import com.background.gl.helper.ColorShaderProgram;
import com.background.gl.helper.TextureShaderProgram;
import com.background.gl.objects.GLCircle;
import com.background.gl.objects.Mallet;
import com.background.gl.objects.Table;
import com.background.gl.util.MatrixHelper;
import com.background.gl.util.TextureHelper;

public class CircleDynamicBackgroundRenderer implements Renderer {
private final Context context;

    private final float[] projectionMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] modelMatrix = new float[16];

    private Table table;
    private Mallet mallet;
    private GLCircle circle;
    float x = 0.01f;

    private TextureShaderProgram textureProgram;
    private ColorShaderProgram colorProgram;

    private int texture;


    public CircleDynamicBackgroundRenderer(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 glUnused, int width, int height) {
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

        MatrixHelper.perspectiveM(projectionMatrix, 45, (float) width
                / (float) height, 1f, 10f);
        setIdentityM(modelMatrix, 0);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 glUnused, EGLConfig config) {
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

        table = new Table();
        mallet = new Mallet();
        circle = new GLCircle();

        textureProgram = new TextureShaderProgram(context);
        colorProgram = new ColorShaderProgram(context);

        texture = TextureHelper.loadTexture(context, R.drawable.air_hockey_surface);
        //texture2 = TextureHelper.loadTexture(context, R.drawable.air_hockey_surface_2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) {
        //Clear the rendering surface
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        //x+=0.01f;
        translateM(modelMatrix, 0, 0f, 0f, -10f);
        final float[] temp = new float[16];
        multiplyMM(temp, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, modelMatrix, 0);
        System.arraycopy(temp, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, temp.length);
        textureProgram.useProgram();
        //Pass data into our shaders(u_matrix) and enable/bind the texture
        //textureProgram.setUniforms2(projectionMatrix, texture, texture2);
        textureProgram.setUniforms(projectionMatrix, texture);
        //Bind our [vertex array] data to our shaders(attribute data)
        circle.bindData(textureProgram);
        //Draw it

        circle.draw();
        /*
        // Draw the mallets.
        colorProgram.useProgram();
        colorProgram.setUniforms(projectionMatrix);
        mallet.bindData(colorProgram);
        mallet.draw();*/
    }

}
```

I've searched for multiple solutions but I couldn't get any of them to work. I could really use some assistance. :)

Edit: Is it, because I'm multiplying the matrices, automatically moving it back -10 per frame? Because that would explain my issues.

Edit2: So I changed it from -10f to -0.01f, and it works. But, when I try the same for the x axis, it just stays the same. Why is that? Is it because of how the projection matrix divides all the values by w, so that's why the z changes, but not x or y? How would I move it left and right on the x-axis then?

Edit3: My width and height are 768, 1184. So why is there a big difference if I translate it on the x by 0.1f? Is the width and height 768 and 1184, or 1 and 1?

Edit4: Ok, now even if I remove the translateM from onDrawFrame, it still moves. I'm lost

Comment: translate as in glTranslate changes the matrix, and since you are not resetting it you add up the translation every frame. So the translation is -10 in frame 1, -20 in frame 2 etc.

Comment: So add setIdentityM(modelMatrix, 0) to the onDrawFrame()? When I tried that, nothing even showed up. I'll try it again.

Comment: Ok. I got it. Thanks. :) Do you know why translating by 0.01 on the moves it so far? If I move it 0.05, it moves out of the viewport

Comment: I can only guess here. Maybe it is too close to the camera. But without any image I can't be shure. Another thing. Try not to create any garbage (using anything with new) in your draw function. This garbage will add up and make the gc busy. This single matrix won't be a problem, but things like that add up.

Comment: Hm... It appears I didn't fix it. Even when I set the modelMatrix to its identity before performing any translations, it is still moving when I translate it by -0.001f. I'm not sure why though.

Comment: I found it. Why do you overwrite your global (intendet to be constant) projection matrix with your local temp matrix?

Comment: I create a new matrix called temp to store the result of the projectionMatrix multiplied by the modelMatrix. Then I copy the result, which is stored in temp, to the projectionMatrix. And then, in my shader code, I set the gl_Position equal to u_Matrix * a_Position. Would it help if I uploaded the shader code?

Comment: No it is obvious now. This line is wrong remove it

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong

```
System.arraycopy(temp, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, temp.length);
```

I don't know what you thought when you wrote it, so I can't explain how you failed, you may only ever override the projection matrix when the window aspect ratio changes. The rest of the time this matrix has to be constant and you may not write to it. In the shader you need to pass the product of the projection and translation matrix. But when you multiply it, store the result in temp and pass temp to the shader.

Comment: I got this method from an OpenGL ES 2.0 book for android. I'm not sure what you're telling me to do. This projection matrix is multiplied in my shader code

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
translateM(modelMatrix, 0, 0.5f, 0f, -10f);
```

X and Y axis must be in range [-1,1]